# My ajax calls are not causing my .ajaxStop function to be called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("html")
        .ajaxStart(function () { 
            $(this).addClass("wait"); 
            })
        .ajaxStop(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("wait"); 
        }); 
});

$.ajax({
    url: url
    })
    .done(onDone)
    .fail(onFail);
```

When the ajax is executed it goes to the ajaxStart and the class wait is added.

When the ajax is completed it goes to the onDone function but never goes to
the ajaxStop anonymouns function.

Can someone give me some advice on this.

Comment: Showing the rest of your code might help

Comment: Are you perhaps continually sending AJAX requests in parallel? `ajaxStop()` only triggers the handler when the last active AJAX request returns or fails. As long as at least one request is in progress, the handler will not be called.

Comment: what if you change ajaxStop() into ajaxComplete() ?

Comment: Checked with fiddler. There's just one Ajax request going out and it returns with status 200.

Comment: I added ajaxComplete. I can see other code go to that but not the above code.

Comment: I found out I was getting an error with a variable not defined that was causing an exception. I guess this stopped it going to the onCompleted event. Thanks for advice above. Sam